# How to display Name to new page after register and login ASP.net using VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have database
ID autoincrement,
Name Varchar,
Username Varchar,
Password Varchar (notMD5)

Case: I want to display the name who register and login on the new page as Hello "Name" in ASP.net using VB.
Component:

## Signupaspx

Textbox name is nmText,
Textbox Username is usrText,
Password Textbox is pwdText

## Loginaspx

Username is userText,
Password is passText

## Helloaspx

Label for display the name is LogsuccesText

Please help me....

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Post the code you have tried and you will get clarified.

Comment: [ASP.NET Session State Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx): "...session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application..."

Answer (score 0):

try this,

Login.aspx

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        User Name
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Password
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="Login" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Login.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub Login(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Session("UserName") = Me.txtUserName.Text.Trim()
    Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx")
End Sub
```

Home.aspx Html

```
    <div>
   <asp:Label ID="lblWelcomeMessage" Text="" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Home.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then

        If Session("UserName") IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.lblWelcomeMessage.Text = String.Format("Welcome {0}", Session("UserName").ToString())
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks  bro, Solved